# Executing JSON link in PHP and parsing the contents

Tags: php, json, parsing, curl, file-get-contents

json url :
http://www.nseindia.com/homepage/Indices1.json

I am able to get the json output whenever i am executing this link directly in my address bar of the browser.

When i try to use php file_get_contents() or using curl i am unable to retrieve json output from the above url in my php file on my website on another shared server.

using curl i get the following response :

Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.nseindia.com/homepage/Indices1.json" on this server.

I need to have that json data decoded using php in my application.

Comment: Ask the provider of the source file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site is blocking cURL requests. You could likely get around it by spoofing your user agent, but it'd be a bit rude to disrespect their clear desire not to have the JSON data scraped by other servers.